# Calling a python function parallely from two different files

Tags: python

Let's say we have two files file1.py and file2.py

file1.py:

```
  from sample import common_func
    common_func()
```

file2.py:

```
  from sample import common_func
    common_func()
```

sample.py:

```
import time
def common_func():
    print("I am common_func")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("After sleep")
```

Here we are calling common_func present in sample.py from two other files (file1,file2) in parallel/concurrent. Our target is, if file1.py called common_func first then file2.py has to wait till file1 completes using common_func.

Please help me in achieving this behavior.

Comment: Multithreaded or multiprocess?

Comment: I would highly suggest you look into multithreading. Threads will have the ability to wait for one or the other.

Comment: How are you running `file1.py` and `file2.py`?

Comment: If this is a multithreaded app, `threading.Lock` is good. If one process spawns the other, `multirpocessing.Lock` is a good choice. If they are completely independent executions, you may need a file system based named lock, which is different per platform. We ask the questions because they are important for the answer.

Comment: @Jasmijn I am running it using spark-submit file1.py

Comment: @tdelaney.  But here I am trying to call the same function from two different files. Can you please explain with an example??

Comment: But how are these two files run? Maybe a program imports them both and uses threads to code in them. Maybe you open a console and execute `python3 file.py` and later execute `python3 file2.py`. Can you give us a short running example?

Comment: @tdelaney. I will open two tabs, say linux terminals. And trigger both files parallely.

Comment: Just realized its getting late for me, but here's a quick run down. Look into named locks which vary by operating system - but I think there are python modules out there that implement them. `common_func` can grab the lock to do its work. If another instance runs, it waits on the lock for its turn in line.

Comment: @tdelaney. No problem. You can tell me whenever you are free. But please help me in finding a solution.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Does this need to be cross platform?

Comment: I will use linux. Did you find anyway to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If file1.py and file2.py are long running processes then you can use a code like below to communicate with each other and listen if file1.py functionality has been finished yet, if it is then you can start file2.py code or else sleep.

Example Code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['program', 'arg1'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
rc = p.returncode
```